# Specific URL does not work with wireless router, but works fine when connected to physical modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a cable modem through RCN that is connected to an Apple Airport Extreme (brand new).  When I connect the computer to the cable modem physically, everything works fine.  When I set up a wifi network and connect through that, everything works fine, EXCEPT for a domain that is my personal page that is hosted on GoDaddy.com. (http://elizabethmoran.com)

I don't know how to debug this problem.  If I connect to a VPN (through the wifi), then the site works fine again.  But without the VPN through the wireless router I just get a timeout.

Pinging google works fine:

```
laserson@rigatoni:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (74.125.226.148): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 74.125.226.148: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=15.119 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.226.148: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=19.110 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.226.148: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=27.054 ms
64 bytes from 74.125.226.148: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=21.344 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 15.119/20.657/27.054/4.314 ms
```

Pinging elizabethmoran.com does not:

```
laserson@rigatoni:~$ ping elizabethmoran.com
PING elizabethmoran.com (97.74.144.83): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
^C
--- elizabethmoran.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Traceroute on google terminates rapidly:

```
laserson@rigatoni:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute: Warning: google.com has multiple addresses; using 74.125.226.148
traceroute to google.com (74.125.226.148), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  4.386 ms  0.870 ms  0.657 ms
 2  bdl1.sbo-ubr1.sbo.ma.cable.rcn.net (10.16.64.1)  15.465 ms  16.008 ms  9.406 ms
 3  vl200.aggr1.sbo.ma.rcn.net (209.6.160.100)  9.962 ms  7.675 ms  7.942 ms
 4  tge1-1.core1.sbo.ma.rcn.net (207.172.15.140)  9.947 ms  7.749 ms  7.887 ms
 5  tge1-4.core1.nyw.ny.rcn.net (207.172.19.219)  119.990 ms  174.745 ms  207.707 ms
 6  port-chan2.border1.nyw.ny.rcn.net (207.172.15.92)  13.825 ms  13.335 ms  22.148 ms
 7  207.172.9.126 (207.172.9.126)  51.993 ms  16.618 ms  15.159 ms
 8  72.14.238.232 (72.14.238.232)  17.992 ms  18.013 ms  22.085 ms
 9  216.239.48.44 (216.239.48.44)  16.073 ms  18.006 ms  15.869 ms
10  74.125.226.148 (74.125.226.148)  16.380 ms  18.032 ms  22.648 ms
```

Traceroute on elizabethmoran.com never finishes:

```
laserson@rigatoni:~$ traceroute elizabethmoran.com
traceroute to elizabethmoran.com (97.74.144.83), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.0.1.1 (10.0.1.1)  2.790 ms  0.703 ms  0.739 ms
 2  bdl1.sbo-ubr1.sbo.ma.cable.rcn.net (10.16.64.1)  10.633 ms  13.620 ms  10.712 ms
 3  vl200.aggr1.sbo.ma.rcn.net (209.6.160.100)  16.901 ms  11.918 ms  146.751 ms
 4  tge2-1.core4.sbo.ma.rcn.net (207.172.15.156)  21.576 ms  15.395 ms  14.443 ms
 5  tge2-4.core4.chsl.il.rcn.net (207.172.19.233)  185.286 ms  197.835 ms  204.685 ms
 6  tge3-3.border2.eqnx.il.rcn.net (207.172.19.15)  39.404 ms  38.517 ms  41.792 ms
 7  mpr1.ord7.us (206.223.119.86)  37.832 ms  38.180 ms  41.153 ms
 8  xe-2-2-0.cr1.ord2.us.above.net (64.125.26.249)  172.944 ms  40.119 ms  43.902 ms
 9  xe-0-2-0.cr1.dfw2.us.above.net (64.125.30.61)  69.867 ms  69.534 ms  89.503 ms
10  xe-2-1-0.cr1.iah1.us.above.net (64.125.30.57)  70.964 ms  72.459 ms  73.129 ms
11  xe-1-1-0.mpr3.phx2.us.above.net (64.125.30.149)  93.314 ms  94.734 ms  94.816 ms
12  64.124.196.38.allocated.above.net (64.124.196.38)  207.411 ms  97.502 ms  106.455 ms
13  ip-208-109-112-153.ip.secureserver.net (208.109.112.153)  111.260 ms  97.948 ms  93.925 ms
14  ip-208-109-112-142.ip.secureserver.net (208.109.112.142)  95.488 ms  94.975 ms  98.032 ms
15  ip-216-69-188-77.ip.secureserver.net (216.69.188.77)  214.700 ms  95.902 ms  96.070 ms
16  ip-208-109-112-2.ip.secureserver.net (208.109.112.2)  98.641 ms  99.744 ms  101.845 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
traceroute: wrote elizabethmoran.com 52 chars, ret=-1
 *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
traceroute: wrote elizabethmoran.com 52 chars, ret=-1
 *
31  * * *
32  *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
traceroute: wrote elizabethmoran.com 52 chars, ret=-1
 * *
33  * * *
34  * * *
35  * * *
36  * * *
37  * * *
38  * * *
39  * * *
40  * * *
41  * * *
42  * * *
43  * * *
44  * * *
45  * * *
46  * * *
47  *^C
```

Any help is much appreciated...thanks!

Uri

Comment: Run the AirPort Utility and check the firmware version you have on your new base station. If it's not 7.5.2, update to 7.5.2 and re-test. Apple shipped 7.5.2 in December, but it's possible your new base station was sitting on a shelf somewhere and still has an outdated firmware version on it. Also, can you update your Question with the results of the elizabethmoran.com pings and traceroutes when you're connected directly to your cable modem?

Comment: This looks like a DNS issue. Like Spiff suggested, directly connect to the modem and try again. If that is successful then you'll need to tweak your router's DNS settings or manually assign DNS to each device.